# .bandnames() as String

Tags: google-earth-engine, string, band

```js
var bandname = ee.String(ee.ImageCollection.first().bandNames())
```

gets a print of:

[image]

using

```js
ee.Image.regexpRename(bandname, new_name)
```

or using

```js
var bandname = ee.String(bandname)
```

results in :

[image]

```js
print(band_name[0],'bandname')
```

returns

[image]

How do I call/convert the Bandname as/to String?

Comment: Looks like [`Image.bandNames`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagebandnames) returns a List. What about `var bandname = ee.String(bandname[0])` (mind the index 0)?

Comment: tried it and edited the original post

Comment: Uhm, you wrote `band_name[0]` with underscore. Was it a typo?

Comment: no, sry , should have altered the code for posting here. with underscore was my original code

Answer (score 2):

Stefan was almost there. `Image.bandNames` returns a `ee.List` and not a JavaScript `list`. So if you have a single band image and you want to get the name of the band you have to use the method `get`:

```js
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
var bandname = ee.String(imageCollection.first().bandNames().get(0))
print(bandname)
```

Comment: how does one get all the values? .get(0:) like in python doesnt work

Comment: you mean the list of values?

Comment: i got it, simply with ee.Image.bandnames() , sry for my impatience